# PDSOE Custom Toolbar option "Send file name of the current selection" with multi select?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am playing around with adding some custom tools to my PSDOE. I have added a new toolbar entry to experiment with the OpenEdge Customization Options. I have checked the option "Send file name of the current selection" and modified the procedure it is calling to have a single input parameter to get the selected file name when it is clicked.

This works great on a single select. When I start messing around with a multi select of files in the project explorer, it only passes the last one selected into the procedure file.

[image: Here is what my action looks like]

```html
ROUTINE-LEVEL on error undo, throw.
 
define input parameter ip_cParameters as character no-undo.
 
{adecomm/oeideservice.i}
 
/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */
 
define variable cParamters          as character no-undo. 
define variable cFileName           as character no-undo.
define variable cProjectName        as character no-undo.
define variable cProjectDisplayName as character no-undo.

assign
  cParamters          = entry( 1, ip_cParameters, chr(3) )
  cFileName           = entry( 2, ip_cParameters, chr(3) )
  cProjectName        = getProjectName()
  cProjectDisplayName = getProjectDisplayName().
   
message 
  "Parameters: " cParamters skip(1)
  "FileName: " cFileName skip(1)
  "Project Name: " cProjectName skip(1)
  "Project Display Name: " cProjectDisplayName skip(1)
  view-as alert-box title "info".
```

Comment: This thread on communities suggests that writing a Java plugin may be the way forward for what you want to do. https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_development/f/19/t/21982

Comment: @jdpjamesp thanks. That's the route I assumed I would have to go. Just wanted to see if there wasn't a simple option using things I have already set up instead of setting up a java dev environment.